# Can R return the value of column B under the condition that the value of column A is x?

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` with 2 columns. I want the script to return the value of `observations` if I provide the value `ID`. The values in `ID` are unique.

```
ID = c("A","B","C","D")
observations = c(3,4,3,2)
d = data.frame(ID, observations)

  ID observations
1  A            3
2  B            4
3  C            3
4  D            2
```

I'd like to access the data frame in a way that it returns me the value of the column observations if I provide the respective ID for the row. (Keep in mind that every ID occurs only in one row).

So for example if I provide the `ID = A`, it returns `3`. 
Likewise, if `ID == B`, it returns `4`.

Comment: Alternatively using `data.table`: `setkey(d, "ID")`; `d["A", observations]`

Comment: You could have a look [here](http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option using dplyr

```
require(dplyr)
ID = c("A","B","C","D")    
observations = c("3","4","3","2")    
d = data.frame(ID, observations)

d %>% 
    filter(ID == "D") %>%
    select(observations)
```